# Memory leak with spring-boot actuator InMemoryAuditEventRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm facing memory leak in my spring-boot application and after heapdump analysis with Eclipse MAT, it points potential memory in spring boot actuator: precisely with InMemoryAuditEventRepository (audit events).

```
One instance of "org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.InMemoryAuditEventRepository" loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xe7020a30" occupies 210 676 784 (57,25%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEvent[]" loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xe7020a30".

Keywords
org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.InMemoryAuditEventRepository
org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEvent[]
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xe7020a30
```

What's the best way to disable this in-memory audit event:

1. Remove spring-boot-acturtor dependency
2. management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
3. endpoints.auditevents.enabled=false

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is very big issue with hibernate usage with spring boot applications, which is quite often causing memory leaks. to verify that it is not your case, please check your Reposittories and make sure you do not have any ```select``` query with ```in```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! didn't know about that! may be of a great help.

Comment: no proble, it is not a very public information let's say and I struggled a long time to find that issue. Also, if it is your issue solution, please let me know and I make my comment an answer so you can choose it as correct. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not really my issue in fact. My pb has something to do with spring boot actuator exposing endpoints metrics and specifically audit events consuming lot of memories.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same finding...

After some investigation found it is not a leak but rather Spring boot storing the last 4000 Security (logging in) Audit Events. It will grow to that number and then remain there...

You can create your own implementation and then write it out to Cache or DB and not keep it in memory..

([Reference](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-authentication-audit))